# How can I make a list print out A1-A6, then B1-B6, etc?

Tags: java

I'm creating a vending machine that has to print out a list of options that the user can enter, but the problem I am facing is that I can not get it to print what they need to input to get that item. The program gets the items to print from a text file. For example I can get it to print this:

> Almond Joy
>   Mentos
>   Skittles

But I need it to look like this:

> A1: Almond Joy
>   A2: Mentos
>   A3: Skittles

So on and so forth through A6, then go on to B1-B6, so on and so forth. How can I get it to print out in this fashion?

Comment: Can you show the structure of the list? Are A1, A2 etc identifiers (keys) for each value in the list?

Comment: @user1849060 as of right now, the text file lists items as "Item, Price, Quantity" and I believe I am supposed to leave the text files to look like this. My original thought was to use a for-loop but I don't know how that would work with letters.

Comment: There is no issue with creating a for loop on `char` - it is very similar to an integer, but you give it literals like `'A'`, `'Z'` rather than numbers. Best thing is to try and write a small loop like that, and play around with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate the prefix by yourself:

```
int NUM_COLUMNS = 6;

char rowPrefix = 'A';
int colPrefix = 1;

Scanner s = new Scanner("/path/to/file.txt");
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String product = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(rowPrefix) + colPrefix + ": " + product);

    colPrefix++;
    if (colPrefix == NUM_COLUMNS) {
        colPrefix = 1;
        rowPrefix++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I would have to create a char for B, C, and so forth as well?

Comment: @RyanDorman - no, the `rowPrefix` takes care of it. Note the `if` statement - if the `colPrefix` is reset, `rowPrefix` is incremented, so it moves from 'A' to 'B' to 'C', etc. Note: There's a slight assumption here that we won't pass 'Z'.

Comment: I Implimented this code similar to how you stated, but for some reason it is printing a number instead of the letter. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: @RyanDorman I keep forgetting about `+`'s associativity, sorry about that. `String.valueOf` (as edited into my answer) should take care of it. Alternatively, you could use a `StringBuilder` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not totally clear about the structure of your list. But anyways, I will show you example in respect to string[]. Lets say you have stored the list in an array.

```
String[] strArr = { "Almonds", "Mentos", "Skitties" };
// Create this to change the title from A, B, etc
char title = 'A';
int counter = 0;

// Print all items in a for loop
for(int i=0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
   // Increment Counter by 1
   ++counter;
   // Print the item, by adding 'A' increment the value of i
   System.out.println(char + counter + ": " + strArr[i]);
  // Check if it has reached 6 or not 
  if (i == 5) { // loop starts from 0, so 5 == 6 items
      char = 'B';
      // Change the counter to 0, so it again starts from 1
      counter = 0; 
  }
}
```

This will print :

```
A1: Almond
A2: Mentos
A3: Skitties
....
A6: 
B1:
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that it would then print out B1: after it hits A6: ?

Answer (score 2):

I would create an iterator class here which gives me the wanted things in succession.

Note that the code is **untested** and might not work, but you'll see the intention.

```
class Numerator implements Iterator<String> {
    int num = 0;
    INT MAXNUM = 6;

    boolean hasNext() {
        return false;
        return num < 26 * MAXNUM; // whatever you prefer
    }

    String next() {
        int col = num / MAXNUM + 1;
        int row = num % MAXNUM + 1;
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder()
        do {
            res.append('A' + (col % 26) - 1)
            col /= 26
        } while (col > 0)
        res = res.reverse();
        res.append(row)
        this.num++; // advance!
        return res.toString();
    }        
}
```

You can use it then like

```
Numerator n = new Numerator();
for (String s: mystrings) {
    System.out.println(n.next() + ": " + s);
}
```

It assumes that after 'Z' you get 'AA', 'AB' and so on.